# Why java allows not save assignment with generic types

Tags: java, generics, casting, classcastexception

Hello I am prepаring for ocp and can not understand why java compiler allows not save assignment?
For example:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Callable c = () -> 2;
Future<String> submit = executorService.submit(c);
System.out.println(submit.get().length());
```

Why compiler not enforce me add explicit cast:

```
 Future<String> submit = (Future<String>) executorService.submit(c);
```

Can someone explain why cast is not required?

Comment: `Callable c` has a raw type. Don't you think it looks odd to say that it's a `Future<String>` when the callable returns an `int`?

Comment: This is just example to demonstrate concept.

Comment: make it a non-raw type, and you'll see that it no longer compiles.